# how to display image filepath from database to image src using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

i have a `btn-edit` when i click it modal window show's up then i use ajax to make request then display my request on the input tag of html..

```
$('#btn-edit_profile').click(function(){
 $('#modal-update_profile').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: true});


    $.ajax({
            url:'../ajax/getprofile.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:{userid:user},
            dataType:'JSON',
            success: function(result){
            $('#profile_image').attr('src','data:image/png;base64,'+result.profile_image+'"/>');    
            $('#users_firstname').val(result.users_firstname);
            }
    });
});
```

but the problem i encountered here is that on the input tag it works fine but on the image src its not..for some reason i got this error on my console..`data:image/png;base64,../img/doc/ui-sam.jpg net::ERR_INVALID_URL`

what is the correct approach to display the filepath to src??

the file path of on my image from my database is `../img/doc/ui-sam.jpg` and the return JSON `profile_image: "../assets/img/doctors/ui-sam.jpg"`

and this is where i want the image from my db to be displayed `<img class="img-responsive"  id="profile_image" name="profile_image" src=""/>`

Comment: Why are you adding the base64 bit to your src? That is going to expect the rest of that to be a base64 string. Just delete that 'data:image/png;basae64' bit and it should work fine.

Comment: i added tat base64 cuz that is the approach i saw when they display the filepath to src.

Comment: That would only be if you weren't returning an actual path, but rather a base64 encoded image. See my answer, that should give the results you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#btn-edit_profile').click(function(){
 $('#modal-update_profile').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: true});


    $.ajax({
            url:'../ajax/getprofile.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:{userid:user},
            dataType:'JSON',
            success: function(result){
            $('#profile_image').attr('src',result.profile_image);    
            $('#users_firstname').val(result.users_firstname);
            }
    });
});
```

You're returning a URL for the image, that is all the src attribute needs.

Comment: This is correct. You have a URL, so that's what the src attribute should be set to. Keep in mind though that you are currently returning a relative path. That path is relative to the current page address. What you have may work, but if the image src looks correct and it's not working, look at the path and possibly switch it to an absolute path.